# Exclude rows if column values are equal of same table

Tags: sql

```
 ![TABLE][1]
```

Hello All,

I have a table with above records where you can 2 entries for each `N_ID`. I would like to get the records from this only if below condition is satisfied.

Say for example

Status column value is 1 & 2 for N_ID =2 and 2 & 1 for N_ID=5 which means status value is different(i.e Both 1 & 2).

But if you see N_ID=3, Status column has 1 & 1 which is same.

So i want the records excluding N_ID which has same status value(i.e Which has 1 & 1 or 2 & 2 and so on).

In above case, i want only the records with N_ID=2,5.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try option with EXISTS() and check COUNT(*)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test16 t
WHERE t.Config_Type != 2 AND EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test16 t2
              WHERE t.Networkelemenid = t2.Networkelemenid                
              GROUP BY t2.Networkelemenid, t2.Config_Type
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Status) > 1
              )
```

This script grouped data on t2.Config_Type. HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Status) specifies that only unique rows can appear in the result set.(e.g. 1,2 = 2; 1,1 or 2,2 = 1)

For second condition you need this script

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test41 t
WHERE t.Config_Type != 2 AND EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test41 t2
              WHERE t.Networkelemenid = t2.Networkelemenid                
              GROUP BY t2.Networkelemenid, t2.Config_Type, t2.Status
              HAVING COUNT(t2.Status) > 1
              )
```

[image: Table]

[image: TABLE2]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not getting correct output which am expecting. Please refer the above table with records. In that, you can see there are 3 records for each N_Elem_Id with Config_Type as "1, 1 and 2(marked in RED)" and Status column value may change with any combination of 1 and 2. First i want to get rows which has Config_Type != 2, so i will get 2 records for each N_Elem_Id instead of 3 records. Then my condition goes here.

Comment: Condition: If you see the "Status" column, I have highlighted RED color value which are similar like (1, 1 or 2,2) for N_Eleme_ID 2, 11 and 16. But if you see other N_Elem_Id 3, 4, 5 has different value (1 and 2 or 2 and 1). Finally, I want only the records having N_Elem_Id with 3, 4 and 5 without using distinct.

Comment: @Srinivasan Rajagopal I don't see your example in question above.

Comment: Now i uploaded the table screenshot. pls check it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks :) It worked now partially and we need to filter further more since query returns 18 records with Config_Type = 2 as well. I don't want records with Config_Type =2 as i explained earlier. Hence i used the below query and got 15 records now as attached in above new screenshot.

Comment: Query Used to get 15 records:                                                                              Select A.Networkelementid, A.Config_Type, A.Config_File_Type, A.Status FROM DCMA_Archive_Status A where A.Config_Type != 2 AND NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from DCMA_Archive_Status B WHERE A.NetworkElementId = B.NetworkElementId Group By B.Config_Type, B.Status HAVING count(*) > 1 ) order By A.NetworkElementId

Comment: Now the first 6 records are my intended output (if you see highlighted GREEN color) and i dont want the remaining records highlighted in RED since it has only 1 record for each NetworkElementID. Please let me know how to filter this further? I tried using A.Status ! = B.Status but not working :(

Comment: Thank you so much Alex. Now its working :) Could you please explain me why A.Status <> B.Status didn't work and what does this mean of "HAVING count(Distinct B.Status ) > 1" ? Please explain me when and where to use "HAVING count()". Thanks again for the query.

Comment: Alex, One more thing... Now I want the records in other way like Status Column should be (1 and 1) for each networkelementid. How would i change the Having Clause? Please help.

Comment: Thanks Alex for clarifying. But however second query returns the records with Status column (2 and 2, 1 and 1). I want the records only for the N_Id having status column (1 and 1) and exclude rows with (2 and 2). In above example, you can see the record with N_Id as "11" should be excluded since it has (2 and 2 )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
    WHERE t1.N_ID = t2.N_ID
    AND   t1.Status <> t2.Status
)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for replying me. Unfortunately, I'm not getting correct output which am expecting. Please refer the above table with records. In that, you can see there are 3 records for each N_Elem_Id with Config_Type as "1, 1 and 2(marked in RED)" and Status column         value may change with any combination of 1 and 2.                                         First i want to get rows which has Config_Type != 2, so i will get                              2 records for each N_Elem_Id instead of 3 records.                                          Then my condition goes here ->

Comment: It's the fist time you mention that the column `C_type` matters in the query. Can you specify how? Do you want to group by N_ID + C_type and take only rows where this combination has also a different status?

Comment: Condition: If you see the "Status" column, I have highlighted RED color value which are similar like (1, 1 or 2,2) for N_Eleme_ID 2, 11 and 16. But if you see other N_Elem_Id 3, 4, 5 has different value (1 and 2 or 2 and 1). Finally, I want only the records having N_Elem_Id with 3, 4 and 5 without using distinct.

Comment: Tim, You got my requirement now?

Comment: Not really. However, i have currently not enough time. You might want to edit our question accordingly so that others can help you.

Comment: Okay, will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the rows where you have more than one occurrence of the same status per ID

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLENAME tb 
   WHERE tb.N_ID NOT IN (
     SELECT tb.N_ID 
       FROM TABLENAME tb
       GROUP BY tb.N_ID, tb.CONFIG_TYPE, tb.STATUS
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not getting correct output which am expecting. Please refer the above table with records. In that, you can see there are 3 records for each N_Elem_Id with Config_Type as "1, 1 and 2(marked in RED)" and Status column value may change with any combination of 1 and 2. First i want to get rows which has Config_Type != 2, so i will get 2 records for each N_Elem_Id instead of 3 records. Then my condition goes here.

Comment: Condition: If you see the "Status" column, I have highlighted RED color value which are similar like (1, 1 or 2,2) for N_Eleme_ID 2, 11 and 16. But if you see other N_Elem_Id 3, 4, 5 has different value (1 and 2 or 2 and 1). Finally, I want only the records having N_Elem_Id with 3, 4 and 5 without using distinct.

Comment: Simply add CONFIG_TYPE to the GROUP BY clause. I amended my query.